# atlassian plugin sdk: maven dependency not resolved for apache commons

Tags: java, maven, jira, jira-plugin

We have been working on JIRA plugin development and using apache-commons library for file upload purpose as follows:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
<version>1.3.2</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Generated plugin is working fine on atlas development environment but while uploading the generated Jar on JIRA, following error is being displayed in logs.

```
 2017-12-11 09:49:53,841 UpmAsynchronousTaskManager:thread-3 
 ERROR jira.admin 357x1243x1 1ycla6b 14.102.4.74,13.58.31.162 /rest/plugins/1.0/ 
 [c.a.p.osgi.factory.OsgiPlugin] Detected an error (BundleException) enabling the plugin 'com.atlassian.tutorial.myPlugin' :
 Unresolved constraint in bundle com.atlassian.tutorial.myPlugin [237]: Unable to resolve 237.0: missing requirement [237.0] 
 osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.commons.fileupload).  
 This error usually occurs when your plugin imports a package from another bundle with a specific version constraint and either the bundle providing that package doesn't meet those version constraints,
 or there is no bundle available that provides the specified package. For more details on how to fix this, see https://developer.atlassian.com/x/mQAN
```

After going through various threads to resolve this issue we have tried the following.

---

- Tried used different versions of Apache-Common 1.3.2 OR 1.3 OR 1.2.x etc...
- Instead of using the maven we have directly uploaded the .jar file inside the lib folder and updated dependency section as well.
  None of above worked so far.

Here is the POM.XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.tutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>myPlugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <organization>
        <name>Atlassian SDK Tutorial</name>
        <url>http://developer.atlassian.com/</url>
    </organization>
    <name>myPlugin</name>
    <description>This is the com.atlassian.tutorial:myPlugin plugin for Atlassian JIRA.</description>
    <packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add dependency on jira-core if you want access to JIRA implementation classes as well as the sanctioned API. -->
        <!-- This is not normally recommended, but may be required eg when migrating a plugin originally developed against JIRA 4.x -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.activeobjects</groupId>
            <artifactId>activeobjects-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
       <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>info.bliki.wiki</groupId>
            <artifactId>bliki-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.19</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- WIRED TEST RUNNER DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.testrunner.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Uncomment to use TestKit in your project. Details at https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jira-testkit -->
        <!-- You can read more about TestKit at https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Smarter+integration+testing+with+TestKit -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-testkit-client</artifactId>
            <version>${testkit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/commons-fileupload-1.3.2.jar</systemPath>
            <extractDependencies>false</extractDependencies>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.templaterenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-template-renderer-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${amps.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <productVersion>${jira.version}</productVersion>
                    <productDataVersion>${jira.version}</productDataVersion>
                    <!-- Uncomment to install TestKit backdoor in JIRA. -->
                    <!--
                    <pluginArtifacts>
                        <pluginArtifact>
                            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jira-testkit-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${testkit.version}</version>
                        </pluginArtifact>
                    </pluginArtifacts>
                    -->
                    <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>
                    <enableFastdev>false</enableFastdev>
                    <!-- See here for an explanation of default instructions: -->
                    <!-- https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configuration-of-instructions-in-atlassian-plugins -->
                    <instructions>
                       <!-- <Atlassian-Plugin-Key>${atlassian.plugin.key}</Atlassian-Plugin-Key>-->
                        <!-- Add package to export here -->
                        <Export-Package><com class="atlassian tut"></com>orial.myPlugin.api,</Export-Package>
                        <!-- Add package import here -->
                        <Import-Package>org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional", org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional", *</Import-Package>
                        <!-- Ensure plugin is spring powered -->
                        <Spring-Context>*</Spring-Context>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin\javac</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>atlassian-spring-scanner</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scannedDependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-external-jar</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </scannedDependencies>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <jira.version>7.5.0</jira.version>
        <amps.version>6.3.6</amps.version>
        <jdkLevel>1.8</jdkLevel>
        <plugin.testrunner.version>1.2.3</plugin.testrunner.version>
        <atlassian.spring.scanner.version>1.2.13</atlassian.spring.scanner.version>
        <!-- This key is used to keep the consistency between the key in atlassian-plugin.xml and the key to generate bundle. -->
        <atlassian.plugin.key>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</atlassian.plugin.key>
        <!-- TestKit version 6.x for JIRA 6.x -->
        <testkit.version>6.3.11</testkit.version>
        <template.renderer.version>1.3.1</template.renderer.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

We need guidance for troubleshooting/resolving above explained issue.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a 3rd party library. So you need to change your scope from `provided` to `compile` -

```
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
<version>1.3.2</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

By specifying `<scope>compile</scope>`, you tell the SDK that the commons-fileupload library is needed at compile time and runtime. The SDK will bundle the commons-fileupload library into your plugin, and the plugin system will make it available in the plugin classloader when the plugin is started.

More details - https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started/working-with-the-pom/managing-dependencies

Comment: Thanks for your above reply. We have tried using the following options:
- Optional
- Provided
- Compile
But it doesn't work with any of the following.

Also the same is working on the JIRA development mode.

Comment: Interesting. Is there any other libraries you are using that might have a dependency on this library but different version?

Comment: At this moment we are not using any other 3rd party but whenever we include any 3rd party it is giving us the same error. So eventually we are not able to use any 3rd party, anything specific where we should look into for troubleshooting purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Very old, but searching a solution for another issue I've stumbled over this... so let's try to give others a hint how to fix that ;)

Either this was a bug in a older version, or it is the case I was facing:
try to call '''atlas-clean''' before you repackage your plugin.
I cannot tell exactly in which cases this happens, but I can be that the bundle and manifest are not created correctly when simply repackaging.

Having similar issues I was able to get rid of such errors which that "solution" anyway, hoping the best for you reading this now :D